# Why does my localhost/wordpress not have a Link to Login Page

Tags: installation

I have installed wordpress version 5.7.1 with MAMP 6.3 on my Mac.

When I click on wordpress Link shown below in localhost

[image: localhost for all 3 CMS (including wordpress)]

You can see from the localhost/wordpress page below that no Login Link is showing

[image: Wordpress localhost (pg 1)]

[image: Wordpress localhost (pg 2)]

So to Login I actually have to type http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin and it goes through this screen to Login

[image: With Wordpress wp-login]

**Why is the Link to Login not showing on localhost/drupal and how can I make it show to make Logging in more easier ?**

Comment: Which theme is that, twentytwentyone? I think you're right: at first glance I don't see any login links in the theme files except for password protected pages. You could add one using a child theme.

Comment: Hi @Rup

Thanks for the reply

I have checked it out on google, I do have Twenty Twenty-one theme on my localhost/wordpress.

Do you mean that I could use a child theme to get the Login Link on localhost/wordpress.

How would I do that, could I do that by logging in and adjusting the theme appearance ?

I wonder why the Link to Login into wordpress is not appearing on my localhost/wordpress, do you know why it might be happening ?

Comment: "why it might be happening" - because whoever designed the theme didn't put a login link on it. If you [set up a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) you can override the header or footer or both and add a login link to that. But I don't see the link in any other WordPress-provided themes, so it looks like they think it's normal nowadays to not have the link.

Comment: Most themes these days don’t have a login link. This is completely normal. If you really want one you could add the _Meta_ widget.

Comment: Hi @JacobPeattie 
Assuming someone is using wordpress with MAMP.
How do most people login in these days, if most localhost/drupal themes don't have a Login Link.  
I have just done a wordpress meta widget google search.
That looks like that could be a good option for me, I have installed wordpress through wordpress.org.

I just wonder how you would let wordpress know that it is the theme on localhost/wordpress and not a theme within logged in wordpress ?

Comment: @Rup Thanks for that child theme Link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/
I will look into that, as I have installed from wordpress.org , so it could be useful.

I will also look into Meta Widget option as well, hopefully that works with my wordpress.org installed wordpress.

I am thinking maybe though the Meta widget option might be better because when you type in "wordpress meta widget" in a google search looks like it says that it gives you Links to Login.

How do most people login in these days, if most localhost/drupal themes don't have Login Link.

Comment: They just visit wp-login.php, or /wp-admin, directly.

Comment: @JacobPeattie   Are you saying that most people will either login directly through typing localhost/wordpress/wp-admin (as I currently can do)  or open wp-login.php file ?

Does my wordpress.org installed wordpress support meta widgets ?

With the meta widget, how would I let wordpress know that it is the theme on localhost/wordpress and not a theme within logged in wordpress ?

Comment: They visit the URL, yes. The meta widget should be available in Appearance > Widgets, unless it’s been removed in recent versions. I never use it so I’m not sure.  Your last question makes no sense, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

That's your theme, use the url
localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php